# Развёртывание сервера Django + Rest framework + Vue.js + nginx

Tags: django, vue.js, nginx, django-rest-framework

Хочу попробовать эту связку для создания своего web-приложения, с тем как создать приложения на vue и django, а так же связать их между собой более менее понятно, если я правильно думаю, то пользователь делает запрос к vue.js, а vue в свою очередь отправляет запрос к Django для получения данных, после чего vue собирает все данные и отправляет пользователю. Меня интересует как это всё развернуть на боевом сервере и подружить с nginx. Я могу развернуть проект на чистом django, но как быть со связкой Django + Rest framework + vue? Мне бы небольшую памятку на простом примере, возможно есть какие-то ресурсы, где рассказывается об этом. Пожалуйста не предлагайте варианты с использованием Docker или каких-либо других инструментов, упрощающих развёртывание.

Comment: Во-первых Django отлично живет без Vue.js, у него прекрасный шаблонизатор Jinja2

Comment: Может он живёт то и хорошо, но клиентской стороне без vue (или другого подобного) плохо. После того как я попробовал vue я больше не хочу писать на jquery, а тем более на чистом js, это неудобно

Comment: а что там писать? Обработчики событий? Hover-menu?

Comment: Те же ajax запросы, в больших проектах получается более 2000 строк js кода, это неудобно, я не просил комментировать мой выбор, я прошу помочь мне понять как развернуть сервер

Comment: это что за проекты, где на jQuery ajax запросы 2к строк??